# Two versions of the same app in Launchpad

Tags: applications, macos, launchpad

How can I have two versions of the same app listed in Launchpad?

For example, I have both Processing 1.5 and Processing 2.0 installed. Only one shows up at once - is it possible to have both?

Comment: If one of the below answers has solved your issue, please mark it as the correct answer to move it out of the "Unanswered" section. If your issue hasn't been solved, please provide more information about what happened when you tried the below answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes is possible to have two or more versions from the same application.

In order to work, you should rename your apps on Applications folder:

```
 /Applications/Processing-1.5
 /Applications/Processing-2.0
```

The main issue with this, is that usually both apps will share configuration files, and sometimes will be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename them in the Applications folder.
I guess both appear there as "Processing", give different names to them.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the version numbers to the Applications' names in the Applications folder. You can do this by clicking the Application icon, then clicking the title underneath. I have three copies of Xcode in Launchpad like this.